# How can I use where statement in my Insert query In PHP for NOT NULL VALUE

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Here is my query in PHP what I would like to Do IF RATE field IS NULL then Records may not be insert in my MYSQL table. My query doesn't work here.it's says check syntax near WHERE. IT's works fine with out where.I have PHPMYADMIN.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `order`(`po_number`, `vendor_name`, `market`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `qty`, `rate`, `comment`, `media_type`, `sub_vendor`) VALUES ('$po_number1[$i]','$master_vendor1[$i]','$market1[$i]','$start_date1[$i]','$end_date1[$i]','$qty1[$i]','$rate1[$i]','$comment1[$i]','$media_type1[$i]','$sub_vendor1[$i]') WHERE `rate` IS NOT NULL";
```

Any help Will be appreciate.
Thank You.

Comment: Do you escape *any* of those values you're putting into your query? This is terrifying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a `WHERE` clause on an `INSERT INTO` query like that. You will have to do any conditional logic prior to the executing the insert query. An insert query adds a new row, therefore by definition there would be no row to evaluate a `WHERE` clause against. Are you wanting an `UPDATE` query?

```
$errors = array(); // declare this before your loop

if($rate1[$i] == 0 || $rate1[$i] == null)
{
    // rate is 0 or null, add error
    $errors[] = 'Rate is invalid';
}
else
{
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `order`(`po_number`, `vendor_name`, `market`, `start_date`, `end_date`, `qty`, `rate`, `comment`, `media_type`, `sub_vendor`) VALUES ('$po_number1[$i]','$master_vendor1[$i]','$market1[$i]','$start_date1[$i]','$end_date1[$i]','$qty1[$i]','$rate1[$i]','$comment1[$i]','$media_type1[$i]','$sub_vendor1[$i]')";
    // execute $sql
}
```

After completing the loop you can display any errors:

```
<ul>
    <?php foreach($errors as $e): ?>
    <li><?php echo $e; ?></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: How can I do Condition for Rate = 0 then display error message

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT` statements doesn't contain `WHERE`. You should use either an `UPDATE` or change the insert using PHP

Comment: MySQL also supports `REPLACE INTO`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing as a conditional insert.. You need to ensure that what you insert is correct. So loop through your set and only insert the rows that meet your criteria

Answer (score 0):

You would probably check this in PHP before running into the overhead of creating a connection and issuing a query:

```
if (isset($rate1[$i])) {
    // prepare and execute the insert
} else {
    echo 'Rate cannot be null';
}
```